# Mocked Service's returned observable is undefined?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am testing an angular component, to ensure it calls a service correctly. I am mocking the service as such:

```
class mockSocket { 
  getComments() { return Observable.of(['true', 'false'])}
};

describe('CommentTableComponent', () => {
  let component: CommentTableComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<CommentTableComponent>;
  let mockSock = new mockSocket();

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [CommentTableComponent],
      providers: [
        { provide: SocketService, useValue: mockSock }
      imports: [Ng2SmartTableModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```

In my component's ngOnInit event, the getComments function should be called and subscribed to -

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.socketService.getComments('api/jobs/' + line).subscribe(comment => {
    // some logic    
 }
```

However, the ngOnInit is throwing error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

in the tests - any idea why, I am returning an Observable in the standard way?

Comment: Are you using `@Component.providers`? on the component?

Comment: @peeskillet yes, but they don't include the service, that is provided at the module level

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you're showing. So the problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: @peeskillet That was my thought, but I really can't see what else it could be. this is one of 40 tests, where the rest are functioning as expected?

Comment: Hi. I'm having this issue. How did you solve?